# Subversion "Authorization failed" when creating repository

Tags: svn, authorization

I have previously had a repository on my computer for local use and removed it.

Now I am trying to set another one up. But keep getting "Authorization failed" even when entering a correct password, when I enter a wrong password it tells me so. This is exactly how I set it up the first time but now every time it fails. What am I doing wrong? It is the only repository on my computer. I have already tried a reinstall of subversion and removing the cache in my AppData folder but nothing has helped.

I am using this guide to set it up. https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/

This is what I am doing

```
C:\>svnadmin create "H:\SVN\Repository"

C:\>sc create svnserver binpath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\svnserve.exe
 --service -r H:\SVN\Repository" displayname= "SubVersion" depend= Tcpip start=
auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\>set SVN_EDITOR=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe

C:\>net start svnserver
The SubVersion service is starting.
The SubVersion service was started successfully.

C:\>svn mkdir svn://localhost/myProject

Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
c
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> myProject
c
Password for 'Admin':
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> myProject
c
Username: user
Password for 'user': ********
svn: Authorization failed

C:\>
```

My svnserve.conf file

```
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
realm = myProject
```

And my passwd file

```
[users]
user = password
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message says "Authorization failed", not "Authentication failed". Which means you successfully authenticated (i.e., your username and password is ok), but the user as whom you authenticated doesn't have the rights to execute the command (i.e., you're not authorized to create the directory).

That either means that you're not connecting to the correct svnserve instance (you said you already have one set up and this is the second one you're trying to set up), or the svnservice doesn't use the correct svnserve.conf file, or the 'authz' file is not the correct one (maybe specify a full path to the auth files in your svnserve.conf file).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by removing the authz-db line from the svnserve.conf file. I don't know why it caused a problem, there was nothing un-commented in it.

Comment: Thanks, I had similar problem when trying to do svnsync from remote computer and fixed it by setting auth-access = write in svnserve.conf file on destination.

Answer (score 6):

SVN Configuration using svnserve on Fedora 17
SVN Server Configuration

1. Create repository

Login as a root user

```
svnadmin create Repository
```

This will create Repository dir

```
ll Repository/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug  1 16:32 conf
drwxr-sr-x. 6 root root 4096 Aug  1 15:07 db
-r--r--r--. 1 root root    2 Aug  1 14:34 format
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug  1 14:34 hooks
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug  1 14:34 locks
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  229 Aug  1 14:34 README.txt

cd Repository
```

1. Edit Repository/conf/passwd file

   vi Repository/conf/passwd

Add below lines:

```
[users]
user1 = user1
```

left to the assignment is a username & right is a password

1. Edit Repository/conf/authz file

   vi Repository/conf/authz

Add below lines:

```
[/]
User1 = rw
```

It will give user1 read & write permissions.

1. Edit Repository/conf/svnserve.conf file

   vi Repository/conf/svnserve.conf

Add following lines:

```
anon-access = none 
auth-access = write 
password-db = passwd 
authz-db = authz
```

1. Check the status of svnserve daemon

   /etc/init.d/svnserve status

If it is inactive use:

```
/etc/init.d/svnserve start
```

Again check the status, if it is running it will show

```
/etc/init.d/svnserve status

svnserve.service - LSB: start and stop the svnserve daemon
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/svnserve)
          Active: active (running) since Thu, 01 Aug 2013 12:14:27 +0530; 2h 19min ago
```

`Process: 1655 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/svnserve start (code=exited,`status=0/SUCCESS)

```
        Main PID: 1658 (svnserve)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/svnserve.service
                  â 1658 /usr/bin/svnserve --daemon --pid-file=/var/run/svnserve.pid
```

Now, your SVN server is ready. 

Client Configuration

1. SVN checkout
   Login as a normal user

   svn co svn://203/124/15.24/root/Repository/

This will create the Repository dir & sub_dirs.

You are ready to use SVN. 

Comment: This fixed my issue, thanks. Must be because of the recent svn update, I suppose, since I didn't have to do this before then.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `svn mkdir svn://localhost/myProject -m "some message" --username user --password password` and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would like add that in **version 1.6.x** of SVN, I had to change something in my **authz** file.

Before I used to have it like this:

```
[repository:/path/to/repo]
@authors = rw
@readers = r
```

But now for *some* reason that wouldn't work.  I got authentication to work when I changed it to this:

```
[/]
@authors = rw
@readers = r
```

Comment: Is it a bug of version 1.6.x, I also have this problem, after changed as your code, the problem has been fixed, thank you.